# Bad CMYK to RGB conversion with GD

Tags: php, image, gd

I am doing the standard image optimise / resize technique with PHP and GD, basically:

```
imagecreatefromjpeg()
imagecreatetruecolor()
imagecopyresampled()
imagejpeg()
```

However people are complaining that there CYMK logos are coming up different colours after being uploaded. I know this is because GD is doing a conversion to RGB but i am wondering if there is a way to improve this?

As these are often peoples logos, they rightly get protective over the colours used and want them to be right.

I know there are some good tools to convert single colours online but i want something that can be added to my class file that converts all the CMYK colours in an image to a more accurate version of the CMYK equivalent.

As a quick example, a pic uploaded without conversion and then selected with a colour picker extension in chrome gives me this HEX code: #992A78. Having run it through the above scripts, it converts it to this one: #9000F6;

Anyone got any advice for me? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GD doesn't support color management at all, which explains the color shift, so there is probably no feasible workaround there.  You might want to do some quick tests using [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/), which seems to support various color profiles.